# When packaging mi Kivy App for Windows, it is unable to get any Image provider

Tags: python, windows, image, kivy

### The problem:

I have a Kivy App that uses the Camera and opencv-python to detect a QR code. When excecuting the app from the .py file it works just fine, but when I tried to package it to make a .exe file for Windows it crashes  before even starting.

The record log prints this message:

```
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in C:\Users\dtapia\.kivy\logs\kivy_24-02-13_45.txt
[INFO   ] Kivy: v2.3.0
[INFO   ] Kivy: Installed at "C:\Users\dtapia\Desktop\Inventario_semi\GruApp\APP\dist\GruApp\_internal\kivy\__init__.pyc"
[INFO   ] Python: v3.11.7 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Dec 15 2023, 18:05:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] Python: Interpreter at "C:\Users\dtapia\Desktop\Inventario_semi\GruApp\APP\dist\GruApp\GruApp.exe"
[INFO   ] Logger: Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] Logger: Purge finished!
[INFO   ] Factory: 195 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] Image: Providers:  (img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] App: Unable to get any Image provider, abort.
```

I believe it might be an issue with the .spec file, but I'm not sure. In any case, here is the GruApp.spec file.

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import get_deps_minimal, get_deps_all, hookspath, runtime_hooks

a = Analysis(
    ['C:\\Users\\dtapia\\Desktop\\Inventario_semi\\GruApp\\App_PistolaGrua.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=hookspath(),
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=runtime_hooks(),
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False
)



pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='GruApp',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon=['C:\\Users\\dtapia\\Desktop\\Inventario_semi\\GruApp\\icon.ico'],
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    Tree('C:\\Users\\dtapia\\Desktop\\Inventario_semi\\GruApp\\'),
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='GruApp',
)
```

Any idea on how I could make my app work from the .exe file?
Please help

#### Some of the things I tried already:

Since I installed Kivy through conda, it  originally didn't recognize kivy_deps for the import, but doing

```
pip install kivy-deps.sdl2
pip install kivy-deps.glew
```

fixed that issue.

I also tried adding gstreamer to the .spec file, but since I didn't actually use gstreamer in my app, it didn't change anything.

Tried packaging the app as a single file application, but it got stuck in this for quite a while until I aborted it:

```
(InventarioSemi_CMPC_Kv) C:\Users\dtapia\Desktop\Inventario_semi\GruApp\APP>python -m PyInstaller GruApp.spec
1092 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.3.0
1093 INFO: Python: 3.11.7 (conda)
1143 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
1162 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\dtapia\\Desktop\\Inventario_semi\\GruApp']
pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.3, Python 3.11.7)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
2380 INFO: checking Analysis
2541 INFO: checking PYZ
2640 INFO: checking Tree
2640 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
2646 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
2658 INFO: checking Tree
2658 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
2658 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
2668 INFO: checking Tree
2669 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
2669 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
2701 INFO: checking PKG
2709 INFO: Building because toc changed
2710 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) GruApp.pkg
Aborted by user request.
```